# How do I post a "I just registered at..." story to a user's timeline immediately after they register for my site through FB?

Tags: facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-opengraph, publish, facebook-timeline

Thought this would be an easy one...

My site uses OAuth to allow users to login and register for the site through FB, which returns an access token for the user. I've been playing around with Open Graph to get this registration post to work, and have successfully posted a story to my timeline using the examples in the documentation (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/), but I can't seem to integrate it with my actual site.

This is the modified code I used from the example to post the story:

```
            FB.api(
                'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed',
                'post',
                {
                    message: "I just registered for X!",
                    name: "Example",
                    description: "Yay I did it!",
                    caption: "Woo hoo!",
                    picture: "http://www.example.com/images/img.png",
                    link: "http://www.example.com/"
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (!response) {
                        alert('Error occurred.');
                    } else if (response.error) {
                        alert('Error: ' + response.error.message);
                    }
                }
            );
```

Is there a way to automatically post this story to a user's timeline upon site registration through FB? Does the access token that's returned by OAuth give me permission to do this? I tried passing the access token retrieved by OAuth into the post call, but got the "user did not give you permission to do this" message:

```
            FB.api(
                'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed',
                'post',
                {
                    access_token: "@ViewBag.Token",
                    message: "I just registered for X!",
                    name: "Example",
                    description: "Yay I did it!",
                    caption: "Woo hoo!",
                    picture: "http://www.example.com/content/images/img.png",
                    link: "http://www.example.com/"
                },
                function (response) {
                    if (!response) {
                        alert('Error occurred.');
                    } else if (response.error) {
                        alert('Error: ' + response.error.message);
                    }
                }
            );
```

Or do I need to prompt the user to give me this *specific* permission after they've registered, and then have them click the "create story" button to publish the story to their timeline like the online example shows (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/)?

Comment: You require `publish_actions` permission to post on behalf of User

Comment: Thank you Anvesh! May I further ask you how to get the publish_action permission? I'm not seeing many current posts about it...

Comment: I take that you have followed the example, in it they have already added that permission, just make sure you have also. Code: `<div
  class="fb-login-button"
  data-show-faces="true"
  data-width="200"
  data-max-rows="1"
  data-scope="publish_actions">
</div>`

Comment: Ah, so the data-scope tag specifies the type of permission you're requesting?

Thanks!